# How to load an image url to an imageview wherein the image view design declared inside a thread?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
        public void addAttendance(ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers) {
            //tl.removeView(tr);
            tl.removeAllViews();
            //addHeaderAttendance();
            ctr=0;
            for (Iterator i = attendanceusers.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

                Properties p = (Properties) i.next();

                property_list.add(p);
                /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
                tr = new TableRow(this);

                picurl=p.getPic();
                profile = new ImageView(this);

                profile.setPadding(20,50,20,50);
              /*  URL newurl = new URL(picurl); 
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream()); 
                profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);*/
                try {

                      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(picurl).getContent());
                      profile.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                profile.setOnClickListener(this);

                //myButton.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                Ll = new LinearLayout(this);

                params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                Ll.setPadding(0, 0, 20, 0);
                Ll.addView(profile,params);
                tr.addView((View)Ll);


                 // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
```

My code for populating my image is not working because my main method is working on a thread. Can you suggest a code that i can put on the a method ? This post is not a duplicate of any other posts here on stack. 
I tried this code on my other class which is working, however it will blink and blink if the main method(which im using is a thread):

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {                  
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            InputStream in = new URL(picurl).openStream();
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                           // log error
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        if (bmp != null)
                            profile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }

               }.execute();
```

However if i put it inside the first code that i pasted. The ui will constantly blink because it is a thread that is inside a thread. My image to is too large i cant resize it properly can you help me? i will promise to give a check and a plus for those who can help me, and for those who efforted i will also give a point

Comment: You could have used glide library for this! its easier! and android documentation recommends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need use threads or somethink like this.

Just add to your project [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

This libraries support images loading from resources, memory or outside links from web. This will solve the problems with blink and it is a good solution for caching and safe content load.

Comment: it is working, actually i asked this question before but i am lazy in doqnloading picasso because i thought it has too many process. But guys Picasso is so much easy to use. if some of you dont know how to import picasso this is thge link:http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android